# Slowing down the speed of drawing an object

Tags: java, android, time, gesture

I am drawing a gesture on the screen. Can we control the speed of drawing the gesture ?? It is being displayed but directly without showing how it was drawn.. I tried using sleep(), wait() methods but didn't work. I want it show the path how the gesture was drawn slowly.. Is it possible ?

Comment: Maybe you can do this: break your object which you want to draw to several pieces, then draw each one in order and using increasing time with "new Handler().PostDelayed(new Runnable(){...}, time);

Comment: thnx@Erfan Mowlaei .. Do you have any idea how to break a gesture into pieces ? Coz that is stored in the gesture file..

Comment: Nope sir, that part is up to you, I only can think of this much, but an advice for you, try to find an innovative way to do that rather than a simple API which I doubt exists.

Comment: ok..thnx for your suggestion..

Comment: Yw pal, sorry for not being to help you completely...